# Strange C behaviour when using alsalib

Tags: c, alsa

I obtained a strange behaviour of my C code while I tried to use the ALSA library.
I used this code to generate a sid of a device

```
snd_mixer_selem_id_t*
getSid(){
  snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;
  snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
  snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(sid,0);
  snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, selem_name);

  return sid;
}
```

I then tried to acces this function by

```
snd_mixer_t *handle = getHandle();
snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid = getSid();

snd_mixer_elem_t *elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle,sid);
```

`getHandle()` is the equivalent function to get a card handler but this one is working.
The strange thing is that if I use the code of the function directly before the use of the `snd_mixer_find_selem` function it is working. I have to say that I'm new to C and this is one of my first projects, so that could be a beginner's mistake with the pointers.

The error message is `simple.c:282: snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume_range: Assertion 'elem' failed.`

So does anyone know what the problem is?

Here is a minimal example of the code that I use:

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

static const char *selem_name = "Master";
static const char *card = "default";

snd_mixer_t*
getHandle(){
  snd_mixer_t *handle;

  snd_mixer_open(&handle, 0);
  snd_mixer_attach(handle, card);
  snd_mixer_selem_register(handle, NULL, NULL);
  snd_mixer_load(handle);

  return handle;
}

snd_mixer_selem_id_t*
getSid(){
  snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;
  snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
  snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(sid,0);
  snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, selem_name);

  return sid;
}

void
incMasterVol(long step){ // Step is a value in [-100,100]
  long min,max,curr;

  snd_mixer_t *handle = getHandle();

/*snd_mixer_open(&handle, 0);
  snd_mixer_attach(handle, card);
  snd_mixer_selem_register(handle, NULL, NULL);
  snd_mixer_load(handle);*/

  snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;
  snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
  snd_mixer_selem_id_set_index(sid,0);
  snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, selem_name);

  snd_mixer_elem_t *elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle,sid);

  snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume_range(elem, &min, &max);
  snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume(elem, SND_MIXER_SCHN_SIDE_LEFT, &curr);
  curr = curr * 100/max;
  if(curr + step > 100)
    curr = 100;
  else if(curr + step < 0)
    curr = 0;
  else
    curr += step;
  snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_volume_all(elem, curr * max / 100);

  snd_mixer_close(handle);
}

void
toggleMasterVol(){
 int swiVal;
 snd_mixer_t *handle = getHandle();
 snd_mixer_elem_t *elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle,getSid());

 snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_switch(elem, SND_MIXER_SCHN_SIDE_LEFT, &swiVal);
 snd_mixer_selem_set_playback_switch_all(elem, !swiVal);

 snd_mixer_close(handle);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  incMasterVol(5);
}
```

Comment: We need a little more source code context to make usefull suggestions. Please expand your posted source code, preferrably to a minimal fully functional example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What is the "strange behavior"? You never describe what happens when it doesn't "work".

Comment: When using the `getSid` function I get the error message posted above. Otherwise it just works without any errors (when I use the commented block instead of the function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that derive from the `alloca()` syscall

`alloca` allocate in the stack frame, so when `getSid()` return your allocated variable is freed and you end up with a dandling pointer...(and when you place it in the main function it work because `alloca` alloc the space on the main activation record)

It's only a suggestion but I think you should use `malloc` (that allocate space on the heap, so the dynamic memory is allocated until you call `free()` on it)

try with `snd_mixer_selem_id_malloc()` instead :)

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. But I have another function called `toggleMasterVol()` which works with the `getSid()` function (I added it to the minimal example above). Do you may know why this call works?

Comment: A dandling pointer is a pointer to a non valid memory address, so that area is already marked as free by the memory manager, but for some reason that area can also continue to hold your old value, in that case your function get the right structure, but It's only luck, if you add some code in between of your `getSid()` and your `toggleMasterVol()` call it will maybe lend you to an analogue error :D

Answer (score 1):

After having the same issue and doing a little search, I've got a hint for you: Change the value of `selem_name` and, if necessary, of `card`! Find out the correct card name by issuing the following system command:

```sh
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

Then, use `alsamixer` to determine the name of the desired volume control. In my case, this was `Digital`, but try it yourself.